# Oracle error when deferring constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl, unique-constraint

I am trying to track down an occasional error from the query log:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00001: unique constraint (FOO.BAR) violated

It seems to happen when the application attempts to execute the following query within a transaction:

```
SET CONSTRAINT foo.bar DEFERRED
```

The constraint in question was created using the following DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE baz
ADD CONSTRAINT bar
UNIQUE (quux, duux)
DEFERRABLE
INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
USING INDEX
TABLESPACE tuux
```

Essentially, the code that runs this query is doing the following:

- Begin a transaction
- Defer the constraint
- Make necessary updates
- Undefer the constraint
- Commit the updates

My question is: how can the `SET CONSTRAINT` query above possibly cause a unique constraint violation?  I am sure that this is the problematic query, as I have the stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: I agree, you should not see a unique constraint violation until you undefer the constraint. Note that `set constraint x deferred` is not a query. I'd suspect whether the constraint is truly deferrable, or if the constraint named in the `set constraint x deferred` statement is correct.

Comment: The set constraint x deferred can cause an violation only if it is done after the updates (as I it is a DDL and there for forces commit). if you just want to debug the data try to use the log errors http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2.php

Answer (score -1):

From the (docs)[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm]

> DEFERRABLE Clause The DEFERRABLE and NOT DEFERRABLE parameters
>   indicate whether or not, in subsequent transactions, constraint
>   checking can be deferred until the end of the transaction using the
>   SET CONSTRAINT(S) statement. If you omit this clause, then the default
>   is NOT DEFERRABLE.

You have a unique key violation.

Because the constraint is deferrable the validation is being done only when you execute `SET CONSTRAINT foo.bar DEFERRED`.

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't make sense with respect to my question.  I am sending `SET CONSTRAINT ... DEFERRED` before doing any updates.  As far as I'm aware, there can't be a pre-existing unique key violation before you defer the constraint, so why would the validation fail?  I could understand if it failed at the end of the transaction, but not the beginning...

Comment: you'r right. in this case i would check if the constraint on the table is defined as `rely` or `novalidate`. maybe the command triggers some kind of implicit validation.